# meaning of "icy waters"

Tags: phrase-meaning, word-meaning

The adjective "icy" has two major meanings: covered with ice and extremely cold. What does "icy water**s**" generally mean then? Extremely cold water**s** or water**s** covered with ice?

Is the term ambiguous?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not satisfied by [the answers](https://forum.thefreedictionary.com/postst218483_meaning-of--icy-waters-.aspx) given there?

Comment: From wordreference the distinction between [ice water, icy water, and iced water](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/iced-water-or-icy-water.2768354/)

Comment: You really need to add the source of your questions, the quote or online discussion that inspired your question IN the question, not in the comments. This habit  of clarifying and/or  asking for greater clarification *after* someone posts an answer or when your question gets closed comes too late and is ultimately self-defeating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the context, and no context has been provided.  "Icy waters" can mean any of:

- A very cold body of water, such as a stream, river or lake in winter, or the North Sea at any time.
- A body of water with chunks of ice floating in it.
- A body of water that is frozen over, so that it is covered by a layer of ice.

In a comment, the OP provides the context:

> The Greenland shark makes its home in the **icy arctic waters** around Greenland and Iceland. So researchers were shocked when they found one of the ocean giants apparently taking a tropical vacation in the coral reefs off the coast of Belize.( source is CNN: [edition.cnn.com/2022/07/31/world/](https://edition.cnn.com/2022/07/31/world/greenland-shark-belize-scn-trnd/index.html) )

In that context, the meaning is "*A very cold body of water*".

Comment: What about "arctic icy waters"? Is the term still ambiguous?

Comment: @Apollyon "Context"on this site should be at least a full sentence, preferably a paragraph. That said, "arctic icy waters" are likely to fit at least two of the senses I gave. Such waters are pretty much always very cold, and often have chunks of ice floating in them. If the context emphasizes the cold, that is your answer.

Comment: The Greenland shark makes its home in the icy arctic waters around Greenland and Iceland. So researchers were shocked when they found one of the ocean giants apparently taking a tropical vacation in the coral reefs off the coast of Belize.

Comment: @Apollyon I have updated my answer. In future, when quoting a text here, please give title and author (or publication if author not stated) and a link if possible. You have asked almost 700 questions here, has this not been mentioned before?

Comment: Thank you. The source is CNN: https://edition.cnn.com/2022/07/31/world/greenland-shark-belize-scn-trnd/index.html

Comment: One problem that concerns me, as you have noticed, is that the definitions are not necessarily mutually exclusive. What reason do we have for not applying your second definition to the CNN sentence?

Comment: And Lexico.com has this definition for "iceship": A ship designed to sail in icy waters, especially one constructed to resist ice pressure.